# How to print a jinja template which has 'INCLUDE' in it

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

In python, I am trying to print the content of a jinja file ('template1.j2'), which one of its lines says {% INCLUDE 'template2.j2' %}

The final goal is to have a string variable with the result of combining these two (2) templates. I am expecting this to be scalable as I might have 3, 4 or more 'includes' in random location. To make things easier I want to start with 2

## template1.j2:

```
Hello {{ name }}!
Thank you for participating in {{ event }} event.

{% INCLUDE 'template2.j2' %}

Thanks,

Juan
```

## template2.j2:

```
I hope I can see you next year !
```

## Some python code I stared with, but cant find the right method (if any)

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

file_loader = FileSystemLoader('./')
env = Environment(loader=file_loader)
template = env.get_template('template1.j2')
```

The final result should be a string variable (or file or list) with this value:

```
Hello {{ name }}!
Thank you for participating in {{ event }} event.

I hope I can see you next year !

Thanks,

Juan
```

Comment: And what do you actually get?

Comment: Well, in the above code, variable template is a class:

`
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

file_loader = FileSystemLoader('./')
env = Environment(loader=file_loader)
template = env.get_template('template1.j2')
print(type(template))

Output:

<class 'jinja2.environment.Template'>`

Comment: Yes, you need to render it: `print(template.render(name="juan", event="StackOverflow"))`

Comment: Yes, and that is the point... I don't want to render it yet. I want to be able to read the whole file (with its include) so I can identify the variables. The file template2.j2 could have more variables inside and even more INCLUDEs...